# Como enviar multiples datos post desde curl php

Tags: php

**Tengo un fichero con várias lineas:**
**Ejemplo:**
'{"cliente":"860973133011488771","acao":"858395203934588928","motivoContato":"690928542932504576","observacao":"data-2019-09-28 php"}'
'{"cliente":"860973133011488771","acao":"858395203934588928","motivoContato":"690928542932504576","observacao":"data-2019-09-29 php"}'

Necesito ejecutar el CURL para que lea y envia una linea a la vez.
Solo he logrado êxito cuando ejecuto el codigo con un solo dato.
Ejemplo de Codigo con una línea:

**Ejemplo del código para envio de una línea**

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

/* API URL */
$url = 'https://...';
$header = array("Authorization: Basic Q09CUkFSUjp2UThYMlA5dTNCSjE3WVAyS3djZGVhbjJMWHJKUXZZY1BJWjl5aTY1ekNVU3Y=","Content-Type: application/json");


/* Array Parameter Data */
$data = '{"cliente":"860973133011488771","acao":"858395203934588928","motivoContato":"690928542932504576","observacao":"data-2019-09-22 php"}';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo $result.'<br>';  
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Ya con el código par envio de várias líneas no pasa nada.
Me devuelve el error 400.

**Ejemplo del código para envio de várias líneas**

```
...
$cont_lin=0;
$linea="";
$data="";

$arquivo = fopen($dir."/".$arq,"r");

if ($arquivo){
    while (!feof ($arquivo)){
        $linea = fgets($arquivo);
        $data = substr($linea,0,strlen($linea)-2); // quita el '\r\n'

       $url = 'https://..../tareas/manual';
       $header = array("Authorization: Basic VNcm4wdTFNTllMQ0dLazE=","Content-Type: application/json");

      $ch = curl_init($url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      $result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result.'<br>';  
curl_close($ch);

                }
                fclose($arquivo);
        }// cierra el WHILE $arquivo
...
```

Comment: ¿Y por qué un dato a la vez y no todos juntos?

Comment: Porque el WS solo recibe una linea de dato a la vez.
Entonces necesito hacer un while para envio de un  $data = una linea .

Comment: Eso es lo que se recomienda en el Manual de PHP (ver enlaces al final de la respuesta). Es una forma asíncrona de hacer las llamadas, sobre todo porque entre una y otra puede ocurrir algún problema, se puede agotar el tiempo por sobrecarga del servidor, etc. Otra cosa que podrías hacer, si no son muchos datos, es ir recogiendo las respuestas del WS, organizar un solo objeto JSON y enviarlo, pero eso depende ya de tu contexto.

Comment: @JoseBonfim por favor no modifiques el título de tu pregunta para colocar la leyenda de RESUELTA, con marcar la respuesta que te ayudó como aceptada alcanza

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quizá para este caso conviene hacer uso de [`curl_multi_init()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.curl-multi-init.php) y otras funciones disponibles para manejar peticiones cURL múltiples.

Este código crea los recursos `cURL` dentro del `while` y luego los ejecuta de forma asíncrona.

Luego, en `$allData` se guardan todas las respuestas.

```
$mh = curl_multi_init();
$handles = array();
$allData=array();

$arquivo = fopen($dir."/".$arq,"r");

if ($arquivo){
    while (!feof ($arquivo)){
        $linea = fgets($arquivo);
        $data = substr($linea,0,strlen($linea)-2); // quita el '\r\n'

        $url = 'https://..../tareas/manual';
        $header = array("Authorization: Basic VNcm4wdTFNTllMQ0dLazE=","Content-Type: application/json");

        $ch = curl_init($url);
        $handles[] = $ch;
      
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch);
    }

    $running = null;
    do {
        curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
    } while ($running);
    
    foreach($handles as $ch){
        $result = curl_multi_getcontent($ch);
        $allData[] = json_decode($result,true);
        curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch);
        curl_close($ch);
    }
}

var_dump($allData);
```

---

### Referencias

- [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.curl-multi-init.php) (ver código de ejemplo)
- [Respuesta en Stackoverflow en Inglés: *How to use curl PHP in loop with 100 time?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38969181/5587982)

Comment: A. Cedano,
gracias por la respuesta. He probado el código y se resultó positivo.
José Bonfim