# error funcion array_push

Tags: php

estoy intentando crear un array en un ciclo para que me guarde la información
este es el codigo

```
try{
$contador=0;
$items_origin=array();
for($i = 0; $i <5; $i+=30){
    echo $contador . '<br />';
 
    
// Conexión API origen
// ===================
    $url_API="https://api.alegra.com/api/v1/items?start=".$contador;

    echo "--url_API--".$url_API;
    $token = "Basic xxxxxxxxx";

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Authorization: '.$token;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url_API);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT , 20);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    echo "➜ Obteniendo datos origen ... \n";
    $items= curl_exec($ch);

    // print_r($items);
    if (is_array($items) || is_object($items))
    {
        foreach($items as $item){
            array_push($items_origin,$item);

        }
    }else{
        echo "Error en el foreach items... \n";
    }

    print_r($items_origin);
    $contador=$i+1;
}
```

}catch(Exception $e){
echo 'Error obteniendo datos: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

pero la variable $items_origin queda vacia y siempre se va por el else del foreach.

hay alguna otra manera de hacerlo, la idea es que en cada recorrido me guarde la información que trae desde el API.

Comment: Supongo que la API te devuelve un JSON. Si es así, debes crear un objeto o un array usando `json_decode()`

Comment: Tambien lo hice le adicione el      $items = json_decode($items, true);  y me arroja el sigguiente error .... PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion

Comment: Haz un `var_dump($items);` para verificar qué es lo que se está creando realmente. Y, otra cosa que me parece rara es que hagas peticiones cURL en un bucle, ¿se justifica hacerlo así?, ¿por qué? Y además, no cierras cURL una vez obtenidos los datos, ni tienes control de errores sobre cURL en el código.

Comment: Bueno lo de la consulta es porque la API tiene un limite de 30 productos, entonces debo de traer toda la información, por eso esta dentro de un ciclo :$ . la verdad no sé si sea correcto, si tengo el cierrre del curl, pero esta por fuera del ciclo, no lo adjunte

Comment: Si no recuerdo mal, para hacer más de una petición cURL tienes que usar `curl_multi_init()`, ([ver esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/305697/29967)). Me parece que ayer te comenté que verifiques la doc de la API si es posible, ellos deben explicar la mejor forma de obtener datos paginados. Sea como sea, usa siempre `var_dump` en la parte donde te falla para verificar los datos. En este caso, ¿qué arroja `var_dump($items);`?